# Display a date even there is no data

Tags: sql-server

Can you please help me on how to display date in sql server.

My table has data:

```
DATE_NOW:
11/18/2014
11/19/2014
11/20/2014
```

I want to display 11/21/2014

My code is this:

```
SELECT 
      CASE WHEN DATE_NOW = '11/21/2014' 
      THEN ORDATE 
      ELSE Convert(DATE, GETDATE ())  
      END AS DATE_NOW 
FROM  TABLE_NAME 
WHERE DATE_NOW = '11/21/2014'
```

but it doesn't display any value.

Comment: What is ORDATE? Also, this will not work if you dont have an entry with date '11/21/2014'.

Comment: do you want to display all dates and one extra day or only 1 day extra from existing dates?

Comment: Nothing can be understood from the question. Don't make us to guess be clear in what you are asking!

Comment: When you use WHERE DATE_NOW = '11/21/2014', it will filter only that date. Then why do need to give CASE WHEN DATE_NOW = '11/21/2014' in SELECT statement? @user3705485

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check with hardcore value like.

first check with numeric  value, if ok, then hardcore with date value and
finally change with **ORDATE**.

This logic suggest what is the wrong with data.

```
SELECT 
      CASE WHEN DATE_NOW = '11/21/2014' 
           THEN 0  --'11/21/2014' --ORDATE 
           ELSE 1 --Convert(DATE, GETDATE ())  
      END AS DATE_NOW 
FROM  TABLE_NAME 
WHERE DATE_NOW = '11/21/2014'
```

Even though,  you can use * and check the data.

```
SELECT *,
      CASE WHEN DATE_NOW = '11/21/2014' 
           THEN 0  --'11/21/2014' --ORDATE 
           ELSE 1 --Convert(DATE, GETDATE ())  
      END AS DATE_NOW
FROM  TABLE_NAME 
WHERE DATE_NOW = '11/21/2014'
```